# How do I get the composition and stage from an iFrame?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, adobe, adobe-edge

I have a parent window which loads in a series of Adobe Edge HTML/JS files into an iFrame Window.

How would I got about getting the composition and the stage from the parent level?

Thus far I can get the Edge variable:

```
edge = $("#frame")[0].contentWindow.$.Edge
```

However when I try to get the Composition and the Stage I end up with undefined

```
edge.getComposition('edgeLoad-EDGE-9424086').getStage() //Leaving out .getStage() also comes back undefined
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was doing wrong was using:

`edge.getComposition('edgeLoad-EDGE-9424086').getStage()`

instead I needed to use:

`edge.getComposition('EDGE-9424086').getStage() //Note I dropped off the 'edgeLoad' in the beginning`